# Android add Stroke to Drawable on Runtime

Tags: android, runtime, stroke

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020503/how-to-change-the-color-of-textview-at-runtime-with-shape-attribute-on-android/4029945#4029945) function.
How can I now add a Stroke to my Drawable? 
There is nothing like setStroke(...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a paint variable with the your intended color/stroke width/ (also set style=stroke) and then use it in the onDraw method:

```
onDraw(Shape shape, Canvas canvas, Paint paint)
```

In this way, the stroke will be added when you draw. It will not be attached to your Drawable.